# Create a hybrid npm module for ESM and CommonJS

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, commonjs

Let's say I am writing a npm library called `my-awesome-lib` using Typescript. Because `my-awesome-lib` depends on a pure-ESM library, I have to use the ESM syntax, i.e. `import` to consume that 3rd-party library. Now everything works, including jest and I followed this [tutorial](https://www.sensedeep.com/blog/posts/2021/how-to-create-single-source-npm-module.html) to export `my-awesome-lib` as both ESM and CommonJS module.

In the meanwhile, I am also writing an application that depends on my custom library using CommonJS syntax, i.e. `require('my-awesome-lib')`, but jest test suite failed to run because:

> Must use import to load ES Module: path/to/application/node_modules/3rd_party/index.js

It kind of makes sense to me because the 3rd-party lib is pure-ESM and you cannot *require* a ESM package - but it also confuses me: Didn't I already told Typescript to compile the source code into CommonJS (as well as ESM)?

I also followed Dan Fabulich's awesome post on [ESM vs CommonJS](https://redfin.engineering/node-modules-at-war-why-commonjs-and-es-modules-cant-get-along-9617135eeca1) but I still don't have answer.

Can someone help here? Thanks a million.